# HttpTransportSE . call Error

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm student and new android 
I has a Webservice (WFC C#) and when I test in Visual Winform it's OK..
my android code:

```
    String NAMESPACE="http://tempuri.org/";
    String METHOD_NAME="Hello"; // method public string Hello() [WCF]
    String SOAP_ACTIONS=NAMESPACE+"/"+METHOD_NAME;
    String URL="http://localhost:8732/BookInformationHost/BookService/"; // host Service 
    SoapObject request=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet=true;
    envelope.encodingStyle=SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE transp=new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Try 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        transp.call(SOAP_ACTIONS, envelope);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Try 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Object result=(Object)envelope;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello_Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Toast show ("Try 1") & "Hello_Error". So what need i do for get String from function String on Webservice.. 
Thanks to much!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
String URL="http://localhost:8732/BookInformationHost/BookService/"; // host Service
```

Android doesn't understand, `localhost` so either put `10.0.2.2` or your **system's IP Address**. Then try again.. Also Post the exception log what you getting from it.